# Why float is bigger than double after computing same value? Why float can't be implicitly converted to Decimal

Tags: c#, math, floating-point

So many arithmetic questions on SO, specially floating point hence I am merging my 2 questions together.

1. Why float `0.3333333` > double `0.333333333333333`?

Here is the program that prove it.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 1;
            int b = 3;
            float f = Convert.ToSingle(a) / Convert.ToSingle(b);
            double db = Convert.ToDouble(a) / Convert.ToDouble(b);
            Console.WriteLine(f > db);
            Console.Read();
        }
```

2. Why `float` can't be implicitly converted to `decimal`  but `int` can?

e.g.

```
decimal d1 = 0.1f; //error
decimal d2 = 1; //no error
```

Answer (score 5):

For your first question, `float`s are actually converted to `double`s when you use the `>` operator on them. If you print `(double)f`, you'll see its value:

```
0.333333343267441
```

While `db` is:

```
0.333333333333333
```

For the second question, although there isn't an implicit conversion from `float` to `decimal`, there is an explicit one, so you can use a cast:

```
float a = 0.1f; 
decimal d = (decimal)a;
```

I can't find anything in the language spec as to *why* this is, but I speculate that this conversion isn't something that you should do, so you need to be explicit about it. Why shouldn't you do this? Because `decimal` is supposed to represent discrete amounts like currency, while `float` and `double` are supposed to represent continuous amounts. They represent two very different things.

Comment: +1 for answering question 1 however I have to ask on second, even int and decimal are supposed to be used differently but still int and decimal are implicitly convertible.

Comment: @Imad `int` represents a discrete amount, like "the number of apples". `decimal` also represents a discrete amount, like "price of an apple". They are both discrete.

Comment: `decimal`, `float`, and `double` are all floating-pont formats that have sets of discrete points. None of them is continuous; each of them is quantized. The only difference is in the radix they use. The only reason `decimal` **seems** more suitable **to humans** is that it uses the same radix humans use for many things. In terms of the natural world, which cares nothing for numeral systems, there is essentially no difference between formats with different radices.

Answer (score 2):

1. When numerals in source text, such as `.3333333` are converted to floating-point, they are rounded to the nearest representable value. It so happens that the nearest `float` value to `.3333333` is slightly greater than .3333333; it is 0.333333313465118408203125, while the `double` value nearest to 0.333333333333333 is slightly less than that; it is 0.333333333333332981762708868700428865849971771240234375. Since 0.333333313465118408203125 is greater than 0.333333333333332981762708868700428865849971771240234375, `f > db` evaluates to true.
2. I am unfamiliar with the rules of C# and its decimal type. However, I suspect the reason `decimal d1 = 0.1f;` is disallowed while `decimal d2 = 1;` is allowed is that not all `float` values can be converted to `decimal` without error, while all `int` values can be converted to `decimal` without error. [According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.7.2), `decimal` uses a significand of 96 digits, which suffices to represent any `int` exactly. However, it has smaller range than `float`, with its largest finite value being 2<sup>96</sup>−1, around 7.9228•10<sup>28</sup>. The largest finite `float` is 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>, around 3.4028•10<sup>38</sup>.

Comment: But decimal has higher precision, so there should not be any error I guess

Comment: @Imad: It may be that every `int` can be converted to `decimal` without error, but not every `float` can be converted to integer without error, so a default conversion is not allowed even if this particular case would not have any error.

Comment: That's what I am not getting. Even after having bigger mentissa and precission for decimal, why therecis chance of any error?

Comment: @lmad: The `decimal` format is a sign and a 96-bit integer divided by a power of ten, with the power ranging from 0 to 28. This means the largest number it can represent is 2^96−1. But the largest finite `float` is 2^128−2^104. So `decimal` cannot represent large `float`. Additionally, consider 1/2, 1/4, 1/8,… In decimal, these are .5, .25, .125. For 2^−n, the final 5 falls in decimal place n. But the smallest positive `float` is 2^−149. The decimal for this starts in place 45 but continues to place 149. So it needs 105 digits to be represented exactly, but `decimal` has at most 29.